# How to fetch a particular div from one html file and place it in other html file using normal JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html files named `homepage.html` & `dashboard.html` at same level under same folder. I only want to fetch a particular div as my main project has a lot of divs.

Here's the code of `homepage.html`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="homepage-side-menu">
            <div id="homepage-home">
                <label>Home</label>
            </div>
            <div id="homepage-dashboard">
                <label>Dashboard</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="homepage-main-view"></div>
        <script src="js/homepage.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the code of `dashboard.html`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dashboard.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dashboard-side-menu"></div>
        <div id="dashboard-main-view"></div>
        <script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to only fetch the content from the `div class="homepage-side-menu">` and show it under `<div class="dashboard-side-menu"></div>` using simple JavaScript.

Comment: What is the reason for not just copy pasting it from `homepage` to `dashboard`?

Comment: Have you try using `.load()` with Jquery?
https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Don't you know how to use `<script src='first.js'></script><script src='second.js'></script>` tags. Put them in your `<head>` and use `addEventListener('load', ()=>{ /* should be available here */ });` on all your pages. Of course, variables used on other pages must be declared outside the load.

Comment: Actually when the side bar label is clicked I want to show some other html file content without reloading the page. So the code is just an example/dummy of my original code.

Comment: Yeah you can read the reference here https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: `<iframe src='yourPage.html'></iframe>`. But really, if you are just adding stuff to the page you're on, it doesn't need to reload if you use AJAX.

Comment: If you are looking to reuse site components, you might want to look into coding your page in php, which supports `include`s for templates and snippets. Alternatively, you could try to use a component based Framework such as Vue or React.

Comment: I don't want to load the entire html file, I just want to fetch a particular div that has some particular id. My project has a lot of content the code above contains only the required stuff.

Comment: I think the title of the question is now much more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: I don't want the entire html file, just a div which is inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to refer the file which you want to consume. then you use `getElementByClass()`

here is how you import the html file into another html

```
<link href="homepage.html" rel="import" />
```

or using javascript:

```
<script> 
  $(function(){
    $("#addContentFromAnotherHTML").load("homepage.html"); 
  });
</script>
```

and you can view something like this:

```
<body> 
 <div id="addContentFromAnotherHTML"></div>
</body>
```

something like this:

```
 var classData =  document.getElementsByClassName('homepage-side-menu');
```

Comment: How to refer to that particular file ?

Comment: as you said both are in same directory, I assume no need to use just use above code, it should work for you to get data.

Comment: HTML Imports `<link rel=import>` are deprecated and will not work

Answer (score 0):

Since html5 you can use imports

```
<link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">
```

In older browsers the only way is using javascript (XHR, fetch, or Jquery .load

Comment: I only want to fetch a particular id from the entire html file.

Comment: HTML Imports `<link rel=import>` are deprecated and will not work

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could add this to dashboard.html :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( ".dashboard-side-menu" ).load( "homepage.html .homepage-side-menu" );
</script>
```

Comment: OP needs a specific class data not the entire html content.

Comment: My sample does exactly that : it takes the content of the div.homepage-side-menu from the homepage.html and put it inside the div.dashboard-side-menu of the dashboard.html

Comment: you cannot fetch just a portion of a file.
you must fetch all the file, then copy only the portion you need into the element you want.
jQuery makes it easier to fetch the file and get a portion of it with the load function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which you can share HTML template across several pages

**1. jQuery - AJAX load() Method**

`$(selector).load(URL,data,callback);`

The `load()` method loads data from URL and puts the returned data into the selected element.

Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp)

**2. Server side inclueds using some server side programming languages**

```
<?
php include 'header.php';
?>
```

Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

**3. Using some build tools like gulp or grunt or webpack**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-include-webpack-plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include

**4. Using HTML imports**

HTML imports is an exciting technology that promises to change how we build websites. Imports allow you to include HTML documents within other HTML documents.

Read more about it here

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-html-imports

This one is recomended but not works with older browser

Comment: HTML Imports `<link rel=import>` are deprecated and will not work